# Postgres array append using a field from a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, users and groups:

```
users(user_id BIGSERIAL, email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, state TEXT NOT NULL)
groups(group_id BIGSERIAL, name TEXT, members []BIGINT)
```

As you can see from above, the users table contains a user records, where each record is uniquely identified by an email address and an auto-generated user_id field. The `groups` table contains a `members` array which contains a bunch of BIGINTs that refer to user_id in the users table.

Now I need a query, which when given two incoming parameters, `email` and a `group_id`:

1. Checks if the `users` table already contains a record with that email address
2. `INSERT` a new record if no row already contains that email address
3. `SELECT` the `user_id` of the row (either newly created or already existing)
4. Append that `user_id` obtained in above step and append that into the `members` field of the groups table where the `group_id` matches with the incoming parameter. There is a chance that the members field already contains the `user_id` in which case no action needs to be done (IOW, there should be no duplicate values for the `members` field for each row in the `groups` table).

For, 1, 2 and 3, I have written the following query:

```
WITH new_row AS (
    INSERT INTO users (email, state)
    SELECT 'abc@abc.abcd', 'Referred'
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'abc@abc.abcd')
        RETURNING *
)
SELECT user_id FROM new_row
UNION
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='abc@abc.abcd';
```

For 4, I have written the following query:

```
UPDATE groups SET members = (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT DISTINCT unnest(members || array[RANDOM_USER_ID]::bigint[]) ) )
WHERE group_id = INCOMING_GROUP_ID 
RETURNING group_id, members;
```

where `RANDOM_USER_ID` in the second query should be replaced with the `user_id` that is obtained in the first query.

Now what is the way to combine both of these queries atomically as a single query, where the `user_id` from the first query is piped to the second query ? I do not want to create a transaction and run the two individual queries independently and keep the user_id field in a temporary place (in my server program). I want all of these to be done in a single query. Is it possible ?

I will be using Postgresql 9.6.4 (or later) on RDS/Google CloudSQL, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see I think it is fair to assume it will be one `user_id` per query, so you could for example use another CTE (for clarity) and subquery:

```
WITH usr AS (
  WITH new_row AS (
      INSERT INTO users (email, state)
      SELECT 'abc@abc.abcd', 'Referred'
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'abc@abc.abcd')
          RETURNING *
  )
  SELECT user_id FROM new_row
  UNION
  SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='abc@abc.abcd'
)
UPDATE groups SET members = (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT DISTINCT unnest(members || array[(SELECT user_id FROM usr)]::bigint[]) ) )
WHERE group_id = INCOMING_GROUP_ID 
RETURNING group_id, members;
```

Alternative is to use UPSERT:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON users(email);

WITH usr AS (
  INSERT INTO users (email, state)
  SELECT 'abc@abc.abcd', 'Referred'
  ON CONFLICT(email)
  DO UPDATE SET email = users.email --this does empty UPDATE so that RETURNING gives us a row
  RETURNING *
)
UPDATE groups SET members = (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT DISTINCT unnest(members || array[(SELECT user_id FROM usr)]::bigint[]) ) )
WHERE group_id = INCOMING_GROUP_ID 
RETURNING group_id, members;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I am using the UPSERT version as it is more readable. It just did not occur to me that I could have done a dummy UPDATE. I have accepted the answer. Can the SELECT DISTINCT unnest clauses be changed somehow to keep the user_id s in the members always sorted, for performance and readability reasons ? Thanks.

Comment: @SankarP I think you would have to create your own function for that and then do something like `UPDATE groups SET members = array_append_uniq(members, (SELECT user_id FROM usr)) [..]`. You would have to search for element either with something like `array_position` or unnesting and if not found then using built-in `array_append`.